# Error Using VBA to Extract Data from Text File

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm attempting to extract data from a text file that is the result of exporting comments from a PDF. Exporting the comments to a text file has proven to be the best option as XML and Excel formats don't work very well. However, I'm getting some errors with the code when I try to run it.

I want the code to take data from a text file that looks like this:

[image]

And put them in a table like this:

[image]

The table comes out like this instead though, with the comments, comment numbers, and pages not being ordered correctly, and some information being left out. I'm not sure why the comments seems to be compounding but then the comment from author D is left out.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Format()

' This code determines the users username.  Useful if there is a standard location each person would have the file on their computer.

Set scripting_object = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
localfileName = "C:\Users\" + strUser + "\Downloads\ForumPostExample.txt"


' URL of the file
file_url = "C:\ForumPostExample.txt"

' This creates a scripting object
Set local_file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Opens the text file based on the url for the file.  1, and 2 are options, like read only, can't remember exactly
Set local_file_read = local_file.OpenTextFile(file_url, 1, 2)
'Initialize worksheet
Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'Write out the first row
xlSheet.Range("A1") = "Comment No."
xlSheet.Range("B1") = "Reviewer Name"
xlSheet.Range("C1") = "Type"
xlSheet.Range("D1") = "Page Number"
xlSheet.Range("E1") = "Comment"
xlSheet.Range("F1") = "Date Submitted"
'Set row count
row_count = 2

'Variable tells if comments needs to be written out
write_comments = "No"
'Initialize comments variable and comments count as it will need to be added to multiple times
Comments = ""
comment_count = 0

'Read each line of the file
Do Until local_file_read.AtEndOfStream
    ' Set variable textline to be the line from the text file
    textline = local_file_read.ReadLine
    'Look for Page number by checking for string "Page: " in the textline variable string
    If InStr(textline, "Page: ") > 0 Then
        'Determine if comments need to be written out
        If write_comments = "Yes" Then
            xlSheet.Range("A" & row_count) = comment_count
            xlSheet.Range("B" & row_count) = author_name
            xlSheet.Range("C" & row_count) = comment_type
            xlSheet.Range("D" & row_count) = page_number
            xlSheet.Range("E" & row_count) = Comments
            xlSheet.Range("F" & row_count) = date_variable
            row_count = row_count + 1
        End If
        'split the textline at the string "Page: " and grab the second part of the split
        page_number = Split(textline, "Page: ")(1)
        'Change write_comments variable so next time the comments get written out
        write_comments = "Yes"
    'Look for author by checkign for string "Author: "
    ElseIf InStr(textline, "Author: ") > 0 Then
        'Determine if comments need to be written out
        If write_comments = "Yes" Then
            xlSheet.Range("A" & row_count) = comment_count
            xlSheet.Range("B" & row_count) = author_name
            xlSheet.Range("C" & row_count) = comment_type
            xlSheet.Range("D" & row_count) = page_number
            xlSheet.Range("E" & row_count) = Comments
            xlSheet.Range("F" & row_count) = date_variable
            row_count = row_count + 1
        End If
        'First split the line using "Author: " as the delimiter, grab the second string
        'Then split the second string by "Subject; ", grab the first string, this isolate the author's name
        author_name = Split(Split(textline, "Author: ")(1), "Subject: ")(0)
        'Do a double split to get the type using "Subject: " and "Date: " as the delimiters
        comment_type = Split(Split(textline, "Subject: ")(1), "Date: ")(0)
        'Single split is needed to get the date
        date_variable = Split(textline, "Date: ")(1)
        comment_count = comment_count + 1
        'Change write_comments variable so next time the comments get written out
        write_comments = "Yes"
    'Determine if first line is being read and then continue to next line
    ElseIf InStr(textline, "Summary of Comments on ") > 0 Then
        'Nothin needs to happen if its the first line
    'Read in comments
    Else
        Comments = Comments + " " + textline
    End If
Loop
End Sub
enter code here
```

Comment: Your comments are compounding because you're not resetting the Comments variable to "" inside the loop, you only do this once before the loop commences `Comments = ""`

Comment: And I can only assume `local_file_read.AtEndOfStream` is true after getting to the last line, so it ignores the last line. Try putting an extra "enter" / "carriage return" after the last line on a sample text file and see if it works

Comment: Thank you! I got the comments sorted out, but still cannot get the script to factor in the last comment with an "enter" at the end. Also, it is continuing to double up on the comments where it puts the correct line in, and then a line with the same info but no comment. I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is a "state machine" that keeps track of what is being parsed in the text file at any given time for any given line. For the most part, your text file looks like it has two main keywords: `Page` and `Author`. In addition, you are either waiting for the next keyword to be detected or you're collecting a (multi-line) comment. In it's simplest form, the state machine is often expressed using a `Select Case` statement:

```
Select Case
    Case "Page"
        '--- do something with the page number
    Case "Author"
        '--- do something with the author line
    Case Else
        '--- either wait for a keyword or collect the comment
End Select
```

In addition to the state machine in my example below, you'll also notice that I've broken up your code logic into separate blocks in order to simplify the complexity of a whole long chain of logic. By isolating the functions this way, it's easier to focus on exactly what that method is doing without worrying about its impact on the rest of the method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim forumPostFile As String
    forumPostFile = "C:\Temp\ForumPostExample.txt"

    ExtractComments forumPostFile, Sheet1
End Sub

Sub ExtractComments(ByVal fullPathFilename As String, _
                    ByRef destWS As Worksheet)

    InitializeOutput destWS

    Dim commentNumber As Long
    commentNumber = 1

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim forumFile As Object
    Set forumFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fullPathFilename, ForReading)

    Dim oneLine As String
    Dim state As String
    state = "LookForPage"

    Dim keywords() As String
    Dim page As Long
    Dim author As String
    Dim subject As String
    Dim timestamp As Date
    Dim comment As String
    Do Until forumFile.AtEndOfStream
        oneLine = forumFile.ReadLine
        If Len(oneLine) > 0 Then
            keywords = Split(oneLine, ":")
            Select Case keywords(0)
                Case "Page"
                    If state = "BuildComment" Then
                        CommentToSheet destWS, (commentNumber + 1), _
                                       commentNumber, author, subject, page, comment, timestamp
                        commentNumber = commentNumber + 1
                        comment = vbNullString
                    End If
                    page = keywords(1)
                    state = "LookForAuthor"

                Case "Author"
                    If state = "BuildComment" Then
                        CommentToSheet destWS, (commentNumber + 1), _
                                       commentNumber, author, subject, page, comment, timestamp
                        commentNumber = commentNumber + 1
                        comment = vbNullString
                    End If
                    author = Trim$(Left(keywords(1), Len(keywords(1)) - Len("Subject")))
                    subject = Trim$(Left(keywords(2), Len(keywords(2)) - Len("Date")))
                    timestamp = CDate(Right$(oneLine, Len(oneLine) - InStr(1, oneLine, "Date:") - Len("Date:")))
                    state = "BuildComment"

                Case Else
                    If state = "BuildComment" Then
                        comment = comment & oneLine
                    End If
            End Select
        End If
    Loop
    forumFile.Close
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeOutput(ByRef destWS As Worksheet)
    Dim header As Range
    Set header = destWS.Range("A1:F1")
    destWS.Cells.Clear
    With header
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Comment No."
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Reviewer Name"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Type"
        .Cells(1, 4) = "Page Number"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "Comment"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Date Submitted"
        .WrapText = True
        .Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        .Columns(1).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .Columns(2).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .Columns(3).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .Columns(4).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .Columns(5).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
        .Columns(5).EntireColumn.WrapText = True
        .Columns(6).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommentToSheet(ByRef destWS As Worksheet, _
                           ByVal row As Long, _
                           ByVal number As Long, _
                           ByVal author As String, _
                           ByVal subject As String, _
                           ByVal pageNumber As Long, _
                           ByVal comment As String, _
                           ByVal timestamp As Date)
    With destWS.Rows(row)
        .Cells(1, 1) = number
        .Cells(1, 2) = author
        .Cells(1, 3) = subject
        .Cells(1, 4) = pageNumber
        .Cells(1, 5) = comment
        .Cells(1, 6) = timestamp
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method.

I did use your method for parsing out the data, and it does depend on the data being ordered in the manner shown in your text file screenshot (screenshot not a real good method of presenting data).

If your data is not as presented, the coding will need to be altered.

#### Basic algorithm

- Create an object (class) whose properties are the elements we wish to display
- Store each object (representing a table line) in a dictionary.
- Read the entire file into a string array split on `Page:`
- For each item in the above array, split on `Author`
- Split the Author column into Author, Subject, Date and Comments

  - Build up the comments, and process the `dashed` comments having the dash on a separate line
- Store each set of items separately as a Dictionary object
- Output and format the results in a table.

***Be sure to read comments at the top of the modules for information as to renaming and setting references***

### **Class Module**

```
'RENAME TO cComment
Option Explicit
Private pPage As Long
Private pAuthor As String
Private pSubject As String
Private pDT As Date
Private pComment As String

Public Property Get Page() As Long
    Page = pPage
End Property
Public Property Let Page(Value As Long)
    pPage = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Author() As String
    Author = pAuthor
End Property
Public Property Let Author(Value As String)
    pAuthor = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Subject() As String
    Subject = pSubject
End Property
Public Property Let Subject(Value As String)
    pSubject = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DT() As Date
    DT = pDT
End Property
Public Property Let DT(Value As Date)
    pDT = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Comment() As String
    Comment = pComment
End Property
Public Property Let Comment(Value As String)
    pComment = Value
End Property
```

### **Regular Module**

```
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Option Explicit
Sub orgComments()
    Dim fn As Variant
    Dim dC As Dictionary, cC As cComment
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream

    Dim wsRes As Worksheet, vRes As Variant, rRes As Range

    Dim str() As String, V As Variant
    Dim sAuthComm() As String
    Dim lComNum As Long
    Dim sPage As String
    Dim sComments() As String

    Dim I As Long, J As Long

fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt")
If fn = False Then Exit Sub

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(fn, ForReading, False, TristateFalse)
str = Split(TS.ReadAll, "Page:")

Set dC = New Dictionary

'organize the data
For Each V In str()
    If Val(V) > 0 Then 'make sure we start with a page number that is 1 or greater
        sAuthComm = Split(V, "Author: ")
        sPage = Trim(sAuthComm(0))
        For I = 1 To UBound(sAuthComm)
            Set cC = New cComment
                With cC
                    .Page = sPage
                    .Author = Trim(Split(sAuthComm(I), "Subject:")(0))
                    .Subject = Trim(Split(Split(sAuthComm(I), "Subject:")(1), "Date:")(0))
                    .DT = Trim(Split(Split(sAuthComm(I), "Date:")(1), vbNewLine)(0))

                    sComments = Split(sAuthComm(I), vbNewLine)
                    For J = 1 To UBound(sComments)
                        If sComments(J) <> "" Then .Comment = .Comment & vbLf & sComments(J)
                    Next J
                    .Comment = Mid(.Comment, 2)

                    'Process dashed comments
                    .Comment = Replace(.Comment, "-" & vbLf, " - ")

                    lComNum = lComNum + 1
                    dC.Add Key:=lComNum, Item:=cC
                End With
        Next I
    End If
Next V

'organize the output
ReDim vRes(0 To dC.Count, 1 To 6)

'Headers
    vRes(0, 1) = "Comment No."
    vRes(0, 2) = "Reviewer Name"
    vRes(0, 3) = "Type"
    vRes(0, 4) = "Page Number"
    vRes(0, 5) = "Comment"
    vRes(0, 6) = "Date Submitted"

For Each V In dC.Keys
    With dC(V)
        vRes(V, 1) = V
        vRes(V, 2) = .Author
        vRes(V, 3) = .Subject
        vRes(V, 4) = .Page
        vRes(V, 5) = .Comment
        vRes(V, 6) = .DT
    End With
Next V

On Error Resume Next
    Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Results"
    Else
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then _
        MsgBox "Error " & Error & vbLf & "Error Num: " & Err.Number
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")

'write to the worsheet and format the table
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Columns(6).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

    'Format like a table, without making it a table
    With wsRes.ListObjects
        .Add xlSrcRange, rRes, , xlYes, , "TableStyleMedium9"
        .Item(.Count).Unlist 'omit this line if you want a "real table"
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

**Results**

[image]